# Widget in flutter similar to android <merge>

Tags: flutter-layout

Is there a widget similar with <merge> tag in android?

It has multiple widgets as its children, but behave same with this widget's parent, something like:

`Row(children: [a, X(children: [c1, c2, c3]), b]`, (a, c1, c2, c3, b) are all in a row;

`Column(children: [a, X(children: [c1, c2, c3]), b]`, (a, c1, c2, c3, b) are all in a column;

`Wrap(children: [a, X(children: [c1, c2, c3]), b]`, (a, c1, c2, c3, b) are all in a wrap;

Answer (score 0):

Flutter utilizes widget which are composable as such there is no need for Xml tags like Merge or FrameLayout, wrap your widget on one page with a stateless or stateful widget and include the class name in the parent build function.

Comment: Could I have a look at code about what  is 'include the class name in the parent build function.'?